# Column sum on every page

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

```html
<?php
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', '/fpdf/font/');
require('/fpdf/fpdf.php');

//Connect to your database
include("conectmysql.php");

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    $this->Image('logo.jpg',95,10,42);
    // Arial bold 15
    
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-20);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',9);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
 $this->Cell(0,10,'Powered By: Tahmid Soft',0,0,'R');
}
}

// Instanciation of inherited class
$pdf = new PDF('P','mm',array(225,340));
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf -> AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
//set initial y axis position per page
$row_height = 5;
$y_axis_initial = 25;
$y_axis_initial1 = 0;


//print column titles for the actual page
$pdf->SetFillColor(232, 232, 232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf->SetY(32);
$pdf->SetX(25);
$pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'QTY', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(100, 6, 'PRICE', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
$pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'AMOUNT', 1, 0, 'R', 1);
$y_axis=33;
$y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;



//Select the Products you want to show in your PDF file
$result=mysql_query('select QTY, PRICE, AMOUNT from pi where PI_NO="3"', $link);

//initialize counter

$QTY = "";
$PRICE = "";
$AMOUNT = "";
$total = 0;

$i = 0;
//Set maximum rows per page
$max = 30;

//Set Row Height
$row_height = 5;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
    //If the current row is the last one, create new page and print column title
    if ($i == $max)
    {
        $pdf->AddPage();

        //print column titles for the current page
        $pdf->SetY(32);
        $pdf->SetX(25);
        $pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'QTY', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
        $pdf->Cell(100, 6, 'PRICE', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
        $pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'AMOUNT', 1, 0, 'R', 1);
        $y_axis=33;
        //Go to next row
        $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
        
        //Set $i variable to 0 (QTY row)
        $i = 0;
  
    }

    $QTY = $row['QTY'];
    $PRICE = $row['PRICE'];
    $AMOUNT = $row['AMOUNT'];
 $total = $total+$AMOUNT;

    $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
    $pdf->SetX(25);
 
    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $QTY, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(100, 6, $PRICE, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $AMOUNT, 1, 0, 'R', 1);
 
    //Go to next row
    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
   $i = $i + 1;
   
   $pdf->SetY($y_axis +  1);
   $pdf->SetX(105);
$pdf->Cell(50, 6, '                          SUB TOTAL ',1,0, 'R',1);
    $pdf->SetX(155);
 $pdf->Cell(30, 6, '$ '.$total, 1, 0, 'R', 1);
}
mysql_close($link);

//Create file
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I am trying to get sum of a column value on every page based on column value retrieve from mysql table. i am using fpdf to get pdf output. currently it gives total of a column (AMOUNT) on every page. But after first page from 2nd page it is adding previous page values.

If anyone can help me on this then i can complete my project. thanks

Ripon

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using? Without that it would be kind of hard to help

Comment: you need to limit the results in your query. every page needs to be a page calculation. so add a limit with offset that is calculated by page.

Comment: Hi Howlin, added code for your information.

Answer (score 0):

phpToPdf is good library to generate pdf from html file

Use this library from [here](http://phptopdf.com/)

In this library simple add html file to phpToPdf function & it generate the pdf file & store it on your current directory

Comment: Hi Howlin,Code added for your review.

Answer (score 0):

In the `if ($i == $max)` block at the end add `$total = 0;` That will set the total for each page to 0 then start adding the amount to it and should display the correct price.

```
if ($i == $max)
    {
        $pdf->AddPage();

        //print column titles for the current page
        $pdf->SetY(32);
        $pdf->SetX(25);
        $pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'QTY', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
        $pdf->Cell(100, 6, 'PRICE', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
        $pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'AMOUNT', 1, 0, 'R', 1);
        $y_axis=33;
        //Go to next row
        $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

         //Set total to 0 at each new page otherwise it will carry the price offer from the last page
        $total = 0;

        //Set $i variable to 0 (QTY row)
        $i = 0;

    }
```